# Is there a good tutorial for figuring out what a website is doing so your program can do the same thing?

Tags: screen-scraping, user-agent

Is there a good guide or tutorial for people who need to programmatically interact with dynamic websites? There's been a rash of Perl questions about that lately, and I haven't found a good resource to point people toward. I'm asking not because I need one but because I don't want to waste my time writing it if it already exists. Although I'm most interested in Perl, the extra tools and techniques are mostly the same.

Typically, I see see these problems in people's questions:

- Handling, setting, and saving cookies
- Finding and interacting with forms
- Handling JavaScript inside your user-agent

  - especially things like `onLoad`, `onSumbit`, and Ajax
- Using HTTP sniffer tools
- Using Web developer plugins in interactive browsers
- Interacting with DOM, screen scraping, etc.

If there's no good tutorial, I'll add it to my list of things to do (unless someone else wants to do it). Along the way, if you don't have a suggestion for an existing tutorial, please suggest the things that you think should be in a new one, including links, your favorite tools, and your own user-agent development experiences. I don't care about the particular language you use.

Comment: A great and interesting subject for a book. I doubt you will find even a single article that tackles all the tools and techniques. If you've tried and failed then I'm sure I won't get any further. Individual articles you'll be able to find for sure. Also, you may find that this is a sensitive area for some working in specific industries, revealing current techniques may get them locked out or locked in ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I've seen is [a Defcon presentation video](http://www.securitytube.net/Screen-Scraper-Tricks-%28Extracting-Data-from-Difficult-Websites%29-Defcon-17-video.aspx).

Comment: Interesting video. He also wrote _Webbots, Spiders and Screen Scrapers_ which probably has everything that I hoped someone had already put in a book. He also has [a website for the book](http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/).

Answer (score -2):

Look at perl library of libraries. Some html parsing libraries should be made for talking to dynamic websites.
Like:
http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::DOM

But do you want to use web-browser enhanced by perl. Or perl stand alone app?

Comment: I'm looking specifically for tutorials, not code. I already know how to do all this stuff. I'm looking to see if anyone has put something together to explain it to newbies.

Comment: Furthermore, HTML::DOM has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: "Pragmatic programmer" - nice book read, and learn what means pragmatic.

Comment: "Interacting with DOM", "HTML::DOM has nothing to do with this problem". ? ? ?

Comment: Find a library that solve at least one problem you've specified, find tutorials, docs about it. It just may happened that someone put together some docs about those libs that solve more than just one topic. Or you will know what libs are used together so you will be able to repeat procedure.

Comment: And no, I do not know any tuts. That simply fulfill all your needs. (and I do not know if I understand them properly - look up)